# Handling a CommunicationException when connecting to WCF service asynchronously

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, windows-phone-8

I am using a WCF web service from my Windows Phone 8 App, and I would (of cause) like to handle the situation where the phone has no internet.

Problem is, i am calling the WCF web service functions asynchronously, so I can't just try/catch the CommunicationException? What to do?

Here is some of my code:

```
BusWebService.BusServiceClient ServiceClient;

ServiceClient = new BusWebService.BusServiceClient();
ServiceClient.GetTestBusesCompleted +=
                new EventHandler<BusWebService.GetTestBusesCompletedEventArgs>(GetTestBusesCompleted);

//Try or Catch here?????
ServiceClient.GetTestBusesAsync(0, 0, TestNumber);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your `GetTestBusesCompletedEventArgs` class should include an `Error` property when something goes awry with communication. Test to see if the property is not null, and if so, handle exceptions as you see fit.

Comment: I Tried that, but it doesn't work, because the exception happens before the event handler is called. It happens in a generated file "Reference.cs"

Comment: You'll notice it occurs with a green highlight inside your IDE. This means that you can continue execution without impact, as it's a first-chance event. Just press F5 and let the program continue normal execution. It'll move on to your handler with the `Error` property populated.